# Check whether string is a well-formed xml

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have varchar2 column in DB. And this column stores string in xml format.
But not all strings are well-formed xml (some with mistakes).
How can I check is this string well-formed xml or not?

If this string isn't well formed xml, sql-query like this will fail at runtime:

```
   select 
       extractvalue(xmltype(some_table.value), 'Attachment/@category')
   from some_table
```

Xml has following format:

```
   <Attachment {attributes} />
```

Number of attributes in each string can be different.

So when the string like 'asdf' would occur my query wouldn't fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple function that will check it for you;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isXML(xml CLOB)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  xmldata XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  xmldata := XMLTYPE(xml);
  return 1;
EXCEPTION
  when others then
    return 0;
END;
/
```

You can use it as;

```
SQL> SELECT isXML('fdjkasksdf') FROM DUAL;

ISXML('FDJKASKSDF')
-------------------
                  0

SQL> SELECT isXML('<body></body>') FROM DUAL;

ISXML('<BODY></BODY>')
----------------------
                     1
```

Comment: I think it's a best solution. But I cant create any functions in my project.
So I decided to extract data with regexp_substr fucntion.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL function `XMLIsValid` and XMLType method `IsSchemaValid()`
Run the validation process unconditionally. Do not record any validation status. Returns:

- 1 if the document is determined to be valid.
- 0 if the document is determined to be invalid or the validity of the document cannot be determined.

**XMLType method SchemaValidate()**
Runs the validation process if the validation status is 0, which it is by default. Sets the validation status to 1 if the document is determined to be valid. (Otherwise, the status remains 0.)

XMLType method **isSchemaValidated**() returns the recorded validation status of an XMLType instance.

XMLType method **setSchemaValidated**() sets (records) the validation status of an XMLType instance.

Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/xdb08tra.htm) for reference

Comment: It doesn't work when we have input string as 'asdf';
    select
      xmlisvalid(xmltype('asdf'))
    from dual d;